# How to find and unhide a hidden module in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a module hidden in my VBA code that I'd like to access in order to debug it, but don't know how to find it and unhide it. How do I do this?

Comment: What method did you use to hide it originally?

Answer (score 4):

If you hid all the menus snapped to the sides of the VBA window, then you can unhide them by:

View - Project Explorer (Ctrl + R)

View - Properties Window (F4)

Answer (score 0):

Tools>Macros>Visual Basic Editor

Answer (score 0):

Alt-F11

then expand the Modules folder.